# Flask Testing Route '/'

Tags: python, flask

I have the following route for my index page:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
```

When attempting to test this route to ensure I receive a 200 status code, I am getting errors. I've been trying to do it with the code below:

```py
def test_index(self):
    tester = app.test_client()
    response = tester.get('/')
    status_code = response.status_code
    self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
```

The code above gives me a 500 status code. The other ways I have tried was to use the code `response = tester.get('')`, because the URL on the localhost doesn't have a trailing slash, but this gives me a 308.

My other routes pass fine, I just can't figure out how to get it for the index route.

Comment: Check the error trace for 500. It might point to where the error occurred

Comment: Thanks - seemed to be an issue with it looking for an uploads folder in the /testing folder, opposed to where the uploads folder is actually located. All pass now:)